# Facing 404, The route could not be found. Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, custom-error-pages

I am Facing 404, The route `public/livewire/message/software-category` could not be found.

I am using Laravel 9 with livewire and my components are loaded perfectly but when I try to update any attribute value of the component, it returns `404 not found`.

here is my **.env**

```
APP_URL=https://fyp.devndesigns.com/
ASSET_URL=https://fyp.devndesigns.com/public
```

here is my config/livewire.php in which I changed my asset_url but it is not working.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire Assets URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the path to Livewire JavaScript assets, for cases where
    | your app's domain root is not the correct path. By default, Livewire
    | will load its JavaScript assets from the app's "relative root".
    |
    | Examples: "/assets", "myurl.com/app".
    |
    */

    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire App URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value should be used if livewire assets are served from CDN.
    | Livewire will communicate with an app through this url.
    |
    | Examples: "https://my-app.com", "myurl.com/app".
    |
    */

    'app_url' => null,
```

Comment: Well normally your Webserver should point to the `public` directory. Just remove the `/public` fragment and debug your way from there.

Comment: @dbf when I change ASSET_URL to APP_URL, I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Change `.env` to :

```
APP_URL=https://fyp.devndesigns.com
ASSET_URL=https://fyp.devndesigns.com
```

and `config/livewire.php`

```
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

'app_url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```